# Is it possible to export Live Script output to LaTeX?

Tags: matlab, latex

I have a matrix containing large repeated excessively large items. The function `pretty()` nicely combines these items in readable chunks. The function `latex()` does not. The manual for `pretty()` correctly states that

> Live Scripts provide full math rendering while `pretty` uses plain-text formatting

Indeed, the result displayed in the live editor is exactly what I want: beautifully typeset math, with convenient grouping of long expressions.

Of course, this is also very useless, because I can only export this to PDF, not to native LaTeX code. Is there a way to access the underlying functions that create this output, so that I may export the 'grouped' output to LaTeX?

Note: I'm using R2017a.

Comment: On "Live Editor" tab, select "Save" and then select "Export to LaTeX". See more here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-live-scripts.html

Comment: @SardarUsama What version are you using? I'm on 2017a, and it's not there.

Comment: I cannot confirm it at the moment. It is probably made available in R2017b

Comment: @SardarUsama Actually, thanks, I found it in the Release Notes, it's there since 2017b. Live Scripts are still very immature, each new version still adds fundamental new updates. I guess I shall once more have to update MATLAB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available since R2017b, using Save>Export to LaTeX. See the [Release Notes](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2017a&endrelease=R2017b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=) and [Documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-live-scripts.html) on sharing Live Scripts.